# Parsing JSON Into Dataframe & Append Value into Dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing, alpha-vantage

Need to parse a JSON and convert it to a dataframe but also need to append the ticker symbol in the dataframe. I'm having issues with appending the ticker. What am I doing wrong?

**JSON Variable:**

```
income_statement_json = [(json.loads(requests.get(i).text)) for i in income_statement_url]
```

**Output:**

[{'symbol': 'MSFT', 'quarterlyReports': [{'fiscalDateEnding': '2022-06-30', 'reportedCurrency': 'USD', 'grossProfit': '135620000000', 'totalRevenue': '196109000000'}, {'fiscalDateEnding': '2021-06-30', 'reportedCurrency': 'USD', 'grossProfit': '115856000000', 'totalRevenue': '165936000000'}]}, [{'symbol': AAPL, 'quarterlyReports': [{'fiscalDateEnding': '2022-06-30', 'reportedCurrency': 'USD', 'grossProfit': '125620000000', 'totalRevenue': '196109000000'}, {'fiscalDateEnding': '2021-06-30', 'reportedCurrency': 'USD', 'grossProfit': '105856000000', 'totalRevenue': '165936000000'}]}]

**Want:**

```
symbol  fiscalDateEnding    reportedCurrency    grossProfit totalRevenue
MSFT    2022-06-30          USD                 13562000000 19610900000
MSFT    2021-06-30          USD                 11585600000 16593600000
AAPL    2022-06-30          USD                 12562000000 19610900000
AAPL    2021-06-30          USD                 10585600000 16593600000
```

**Code:**

```
data = [(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(i['quarterlyReports'] , orient = 'index').sort_index(axis = 1).assign(ticker = i['quarterlyReports']['symbol'])) for i in income_statement_json]
```

**Error Message:**

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can flatten the list first

```py
def flatten(x):
    if isinstance(x, list):
        return [a for i in x for a in flatten(i)]
    else:
        return [x]

data = flatten(income_statement_json)
```

```
print(data)

[{'symbol': 'MSFT', 'quarterlyReports': [{'fiscalDateEnding': '2022-06-30', 'reportedCurrency': 'USD', 'grossProfit': '135620000000', 'totalRevenue': '196109000000'}, {'fiscalDateEnding': '2021-06-30', 'reportedCurrency': 'USD', 'grossProfit': '115856000000', 'totalRevenue': '165936000000'}]}, {'symbol': 'AAPL', 'quarterlyReports': [{'fiscalDateEnding': '2022-06-30', 'reportedCurrency': 'USD', 'grossProfit': '125620000000', 'totalRevenue': '196109000000'}, {'fiscalDateEnding': '2021-06-30', 'reportedCurrency': 'USD', 'grossProfit': '105856000000', 'totalRevenue': '165936000000'}]}]
```

Then convert the list of dictionary to dataframe

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, record_path='quarterlyReports', meta='symbol')
```

```
print(df)

  fiscalDateEnding reportedCurrency   grossProfit  totalRevenue symbol
0       2022-06-30              USD  135620000000  196109000000   MSFT
1       2021-06-30              USD  115856000000  165936000000   MSFT
2       2022-06-30              USD  125620000000  196109000000   AAPL
3       2021-06-30              USD  105856000000  165936000000   AAPL
```